# Big-O notation, Python - How do I correctly expand "5 + n(mlogm + 21)"

Tags: python, big-o

I'm writing a python definition that has a for loop of O(n), but inside it uses the list.sort() definition inside python which has O(n log n)..

I've ended up with the time complexity of - **5 + n(mlogm + 21)**

I'm not sure how I would translate this into Big-O, as mlogm would obviously be the worst case scenario in the long run, but being inside the for loop, I'm not sure how to derive the correct answer.

Comment: Not answering your question, but your code isn't indented properly - probably you just copy pasted your code from a text editor without indenting it afterwards. You need to shift to the right everything below `def analysePortfolio(portfolio): `

Comment: @S4M You're right I C+P, will edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the "big O" is the following: f(n) = O(g(n)) means there are positive constants c and k, such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ k. That is, for your example above, it should be O(n(mlog(m))), assuming that m > 1.

If m == 1, then log(m) == 0, so that the notation should be O(n). In case both are possible, you might want to consider using O(nmlog(m) + n))